# Shell script - loop in batches

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a sample script like below, where I pass the server names as comma separated stings and execute the functions for each server. Now I need to execute this in batches, e.g. in first batch functions will call with a,b,c,d. Once finished they will take next 4 and call the functions and at last they will call last 2. I can't change the 'servers' variable. Any ides/suggestions.

```
servers = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS=",";
for server in ${servers}
do
 function1 server
done
for server in ${servers}
do
 function2 server
done
for server in ${servers}
do
 function3 server
done
IFS=$OIFS;
```

Please note that server variable length is not fixed and based on the environment it loads different servers.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why not just use sge or torque to manage processing queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the server list into an array, then use substring expansion (aka "slicing"). You can also store the names of the functions to call in an array, if I (now) understand your concern over the size of the list of servers.

```
IFS=, read -a s <<< "$servers"

bs=4  # batch size
for ((i=0; i<=${#s[@]}; i+=bs)); do
    function1 "${s[@]:i:bs}"
    function2 "${s[@]:i:bs}"
    function3 "${s[@]:i:bs}"
done
```

Comment: There is a little typo: ``for ((i=0; i<=${#server_list[@]}; i+=batch_size)); do``

Comment: Thanks. The whole thing is way too verbose anyway, so I shrunk all the variable names for readability.

Comment: think there is a problem.  shouldn't `"${s[@]:i:i+bs}"` be `"${s[@]:i:bs}"` ?

Comment: I believe so; the second argument of substring expansion is a length, not a stopping position.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for `GNU Parallel` to me. Something like this:

```
parallel -d ',' -k -j 4 'func1 {1}; func2 {1}; func3 {1}'  <<< $servers
```

Try it out like this:

```
parallel -d ',' -k -j 4 'echo {1}; sleep 2'  <<< $servers
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```

If they really are functions (rather than shell scripts or executables), remember to export them like this:

```
func1() {
  echo Doing it for $1
  sleep 2
  echo Done with $1
}

export -f func1
```

Comment: This answer is underrated. I might've used `xargs -n10`, but `parallel -N10` actually does the same *plus* parallelization, which saves time!

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Inspired by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) answer, i've modified the loop to make it dynamic also in the call of the functions.

```
function1 () { echo "f1: $@"; }
function2 () { echo "f2: $@"; }
function3 () { echo "f3: $@"; }

servers=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
slice=4

IFS=, read -r -a array <<< "${servers}"

for index in "${!array[@]}"
do
    let "n = (index / slice) + 1" # n = 1 in (0..3), 2 in (4..7), 3 in (8..11), ...
    function${n} ${array[i]}
done
```

**Output**

> f1: a
>   f1: b
>   f1: c
>   f1: d
>   f2: e
>   f2: f
>   f2: g
>   f2: h
>   f3: i
>   f3: j

Obviously this works with a caveat: the functions have to be called `function1, function2, ...` (actually the functions' name can be remapped too, loosing a bit of dynamism).

Otherwise a more classic static loop:

```
for index in "${!array[@]}"; do
    let "n = (index / slice) + 1"
    ((n == 1)) && function1 ${array[index]}
    ((n == 2)) && function2 ${array[index]}
    ((n == 3)) && function3 ${array[index]}
done
```

Comment: thanks, but in my case servers length is not constant and vary based on environment it's executing scripts.

Comment: @PinakiMukherjee That just requires a small change in the ranges checked.

Comment: @GsusRecovery Don't use `-a`; it's an extension to the POSIX standard that isn't recommended anyway. Use `[ "$counter" -ge 1 ] && [ "$counter" -le 4 ]` instead. Or better, since you use the non-POSIX arithmetic statement to increment `counter`, just use `(( counter >= 1 && counter <= 4))`.